# NumberOfRowsInSection return issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am populating my UITableView with data from an RSS feed however I don't want to return all the values. how do you set the number of return values in the method below ?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return itemsToDisplay.count;
}
```

Comment: How many values do you want to return?

Comment: You can just return the number of rows yoy want to display. Is there more to your question?

Comment: @JeremyHerrero 10 values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is a callback, this is where you specify the number of rows to display.

Trivial answer:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return MIN(itemsToDisplay.count, 10);
}
```

It is necessary to insure that the returned count is no greater than the number of items in `itemsToDisplay`.

This will cause a maximum of the first 10 to be displayed. Is there more to the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what about this code is helpful and how it would answer the question. The goal of StackOverflow isn't just to throw out answers for specific questions, but also to provide a reference for future visitors. Without explanation, this answer isn't helpful.

Comment: The comments here miss the major problem: if the number of entries is less than 10 the app will crash. One needs to be defensive, handle not only the "happy path" but also the "unhappy path". (Finally, the drive-by comment about a link is almost funny since there is no link. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

u can just pass any number

```
int returnedvalue = 5;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return returnedvalue;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: man, did u checked my point when u have down-voted my answer. I was not permitted to post comment. This is not quite expected from a developer who is using stackvoverflow from so many days..btw thanks